# Calculate the sum of pixel intensities for each timepoint of array (python)

Tags: python, arrays, time, sum, tiff

I have a 3D array with the dimensions (141, 2048, 2048) where the first dimension is time. I would like to calculate the sum of values that are present in the 2048x 2048 array (pixel intensities) for each of the 141 timepoints and then plot it.

I tried it like this but it did not work for me. Can anyone help?

```
from skimage import io

bg = io.imread('myfile.tif')

y1 = []
for i in range(bg.shape[0]):
    y1.append(bg[i,:,:].sum)
```

Comment: Add more details, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `axis` argument of sum with a tuple to sum over each image:

```
y1 = bg.sum(axis=(1,2))
```

Edit: The reason your original didn't work is because you used `.sum` instead of `.sum()`